# Implementing multiple Slick JS Sliders in WordPress with ACF not work

Tags: javascript, wordpress, slider, advanced-custom-fields

I've got multiple sliders on one page in my WordPress website. When adding my second with a gallery customizing option using ACF, it doesn't display any images added to it.

Code:
JS

```
$('.slideshow').slick({
slidesToShow: 3,
slidesToScroll: 1,
});
```

Page template:

```
$images = get_field('gallery');

 if( $images ): ?>

 <div class="slideshow">

 <?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>

 <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" />

 <?php endforeach; ?>

 </div>

 <?php endif; ?>
```

I've made a gallery field called 'gallery'
But it's not working, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: is the `slideshow` div loading at all?

Comment: I'm having the same exact issue. The first slider uses just custom fields, the second an ACF gallery. The second one loads with no height if you do "arrows: false" and if you leave the arrows it loads with a HUGE height that covers up other divs above it in the DOM.